# Getting composition name in QGIS Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

In the QGIS python console, I want to populate a list with compositions names, like in Composer Manager, but I can't figure out how to get the names (titles).

So far:

```
composerlist = self.iface.activeComposers()
```

And I get a list of `QgsComposerView` objects.

Now I want something like that:

```
for item in composerlist:
    print item.title()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out an workaround: `item.composerWindow().windowTitle()`

Answer (score 1):

this is another way:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def ListComposerTemplates():
    menubar = iface.mainWindow().menuBar()
    for action in menubar.actions():
        #print action.objectName(),":",action.text()
        if action.objectName() == "mProjectMenu" or action.text()=="Pro&ject":#no objectname?
            #print action.objectName(),":",action.text()
            for a in action.menu().actions():
                #print a.objectName(),":",a.text()
                if a.objectName()=='mPrintComposersMenu' or a.text()=='Print Composers':#no objectname?
                    print a.objectName(),":",a.text()
                    for m in a.menu().actions():
                        print m.objectName(), ":", m.text()
                    return

ListComposerTemplates()
```